# Failed to read response with EJB Remote when using wildfly 26

Tags: java, ejb, wildfly

i am facing problem that client cannot read response from server with Class Entity(ETC List, Entity). Also with Objects of type String, int, Double it still works normally.

**Project EJBServer**

1. Class Entity: AnimalEntity.java

   public class AnimalEntity {

   ```
    private String animalName;
    private String animalCountry;
    private String animaltype;
    private double animalWeigth;

    public AnimalEntity(String animalName, String animalCountry, String animaltype, double animalWeigth) {
        super();
        this.animalName = animalName;
        this.animalCountry = animalCountry;
        this.animaltype = animaltype;
        this.animalWeigth = animalWeigth;
    }
    public String getAnimalName() {
        return animalName;
    }
    public void setAnimalName(String animalName) {
        this.animalName = animalName;
    }
    ..............
   ```

   }
2. Interface: AnimalServiceRemote.java.

> `import com.ejb.entity.AnimalEntity;`

```
 public interface AnimalServiceRemote {

    public String findByName(String strName);
    public AnimalEntity Request(String strName); 
}
```

3. Bean Class: AnimalService.java

> ```
> import jakarta.ejb.LocalBean;
> import jakarta.ejb.Remote;
> import jakarta.ejb.Stateless;
> ```

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@Remote(AnimalServiceRemote.class)
public class AnimalService implements AnimalServiceRemote {

    @Override
    public String findByName(String strName) {
        List<AnimalEntity> lst= new ArrayList<AnimalEntity>();
        AnimalEntity ani= new AnimalEntity("Dog", "Japan", "Type1", 30);
        AnimalEntity ani1= new AnimalEntity("Cat", "USA", "Type2", 150);
        AnimalEntity ani2= new AnimalEntity("Fish", "Ger", "Type3", 3);
        lst.add(ani);
        lst.add(ani1);
        lst.add(ani2);
        for (int i = 0; i < lst.size(); i++) {
            if (lst.get(i).getAnimalName().equals(strName)){
                return "Name: "+ lst.get(i).getAnimalName() +" - Country: "+ lst.get(i).getAnimalCountry() +" - Weigth: "+lst.get(i).getAnimalWeigth();
            }
        }
        
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public AnimalEntity Request(String strName) {
        List<AnimalEntity> lst= new ArrayList<AnimalEntity>();
        AnimalEntity ani= new AnimalEntity("Dog", "Japan", "Type1", 30);
        AnimalEntity ani1= new AnimalEntity("Cat", "USA", "Type2", 150);
        AnimalEntity ani2= new AnimalEntity("Fish", "Ger", "Type3", 3);
        lst.add(ani);
        lst.add(ani1);
        lst.add(ani2);
        AnimalEntity animal= new AnimalEntity();
        for (int i = 0; i < lst.size(); i++) {
            if (lst.get(i).getAnimalName().equals(strName)){
                animal=lst.get(i);
                return animal;
            }
        }
        
        return null;
    }
}
```

**AppClient**

1. Main Class: Myclient.java

> ```
> import javax.naming.Context;
> import javax.naming.InitialContext;
> import com.ejb.entity.AnimalEntity;
> import com.ejb.remote.AnimalServiceRemote;
> ```

```
public class Myclient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Proccessing...!" );
            // Setting Config InitContext
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
            props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote+http://localhost:8080");
            props.put("wildfly.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
            AnimalServiceRemote animal= (AnimalServiceRemote) ctx.lookup("ejb:/EJBServer/AnimalService!com.ejb.remote.AnimalServiceRemote");
            
            System.out.println("Lookup completeted..." );
            
            System.out.println(animal.findByName("Cat")); // => It's working normally
            
            
            AnimalEntity ani= new AnimalEntity();
            ani=animal.Request("Fish"); // => error occurs here
            
            ctx.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

---

```
with return type as String, Int, Double: it is working normally
with return type List<EntityClass>, EntityClass: it throws an error, I still don't understand why.
```

**Error Message:**

```
16:13:28,617 WARN  [org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting] (default task-1) EJBCLIENT000519: Exception occurred when writing EJB response to invocation 61367 over channel Channel ID 79beb44f (inbound) of Remoting connection 38289bc4 to 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:58770 of endpoint "desktop-sanolu2" <1d50c57e>: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.ejb.entity.AnimalEntity
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.12.Final//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:274)
    at org.jboss.marshalling@2.0.12.Final//org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
    at org.jboss.marshalling@2.0.12.Final//org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:111)
    at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.44.Final//org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.EJBServerChannel$RemotingInvocationRequest$1.writeInvocationResult(EJBServerChannel.java:986)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@26.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.AssociationImpl.lambda$receiveInvocationRequest$0(AssociationImpl.java:291)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@26.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.AssociationImpl.execute(AssociationImpl.java:344)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@26.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.AssociationImpl.receiveInvocationRequest(AssociationImpl.java:297)
    at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.44.Final//org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.EJBServerChannel$ReceiverImpl.handleInvocationRequest(EJBServerChannel.java:473)
    at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.44.Final//org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.EJBServerChannel$ReceiverImpl.handleMessage(EJBServerChannel.java:208)
    at org.jboss.remoting@5.0.24.Final//org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionChannel.lambda$handleMessageData$3(RemoteConnectionChannel.java:432)
    at org.jboss.remoting@5.0.24.Final//org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl$TrackingExecutor.lambda$execute$0(EndpointImpl.java:991)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.6.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: an exception which occurred:
    in object com.ejb.entity.AnimalEntity@45251eee
```

please help me. Thank you very much

Comment: Could you post the stack trace?

Comment: i added the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.io.NotSerializableException: com.ejb.entity.AnimalEntity` says all what you have to do, namely you need to implement Serializable interface:

```
public class AnimalEntity implements Serializable
```